# Best optimization package for employee scheduling problem?

Tags: optimization, python, excel

I am looking to solve the optimization problem described below. Which optimization software package would be best suited for this, considering the requirements specified below?

**Requirements:**

1) Can solve the complex problem described below.

2) The package must be free of charge and ideally open source.

3) Ideally no heavy reading on the model syntax required / fast learning curve.

4) Ideally the model can be run using Python or Excel as front ends.

5) Ideally a visual front end is available such that the end users (with zero optimization knowledge) can easily modify the optimization constraints.

**Optimization problem:**

The optimizer should find a monthly work schedule for the 50 employees of a hospital which satisfies all of the constraints below. For each calendar day of the relevant calendar month, the optimizer determines which of the 50 employees are scheduled to work (=1) and which ones are not (=0). So there are 30 days * 50 employees = 1500 variables to solve for, each of which can either be 0 or 1. It is not required to maximize or minimize a certain variable; finding a solution which satisfies all the constraints is sufficient.

**Constraints:**

1) Each employee has a prespecified min. and max. number of work days per month.

2) No more than 4 consecutive work days for each employee.

3) At least 2 free days in between work days for each employee.

4) Some employees can only work on some of the days of the month (for example only Monday
to Wednesday). These constraints are prespecified.

5) Each employee is either a doctor or a nurse. On each calendar day, a prespecified minimum number of doctors and nurses must be present.

6) At least 2 weekends (=Sat and Sun) per month must be free for each employee.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about searching for software package recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is really not a good fit for Cross Validated.  It would make much more sense to post this question to the OR-Exchange site at

http://www.or-exchange.org/

Having said that, these kinds of scheduling problems are frequently addressed with integer programming approaches.  There are are several open source solvers available, and there are also some open source modeling systems.  For example, you might look at Pyomo/Coopr for the modeling framework and one of the open source solvers that it supports. Another choice would be the Scip package.

The other frequently used approach to these kinds of problems is constraint programming.  There are many open source constraint programming solvers available.